# OpenGL rotate object while keeping it in center of screen

Tags: opengl, rotation, sdl

I am working in 2D and I am trying to rotate the whole world (including the object) around one object and also keep that one object in the center of the screen.

Here is my current code to transform the world, all rendering is done afterwards:

hw and hh are the half widths and heights of the screen. p is the object coordinates.

```
float hw = 400;
float hh = 300;

float x = hw - p.x;
float y = hh - p.y;

glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
glTranslatef(-hw, -hh, 0);
glRotatef(level->angle, 0, 0, 1);
glTranslatef(hw, hh, 0);
```

However, it doesn't work as expected. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to rotate only part of your scene, push on the matrix stack, render that part and pop the stack? You might want to show some code real code.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear, I want to rotate everything, including the object around the centre of the object, keeping it in the centre of the screen. I can get it in the centre of the screen, but then I can't get it to stay in that place when I rotate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix(). So you have:

```
glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(-hw, -hh, 0);
glRotatef(level->angle, 0, 0, 1);
glTranslatef(hw, hh, 0);
glPopMatrix();
```

glPushMatrix() saves the current Matrix (all Translates, Rotates, etc.) and sets up a new Matrix. That matrix is relative to the old Matrix, so if you translate, without pushing the Matrix, you will rotate about the (0|0) Point in that Matrix. If you set up a new Matrix, it creates that Matrix at the position you were in the old Matrix.